# Trying to Export the Data from Clockify

Tags: vba, web-scraping

I have been trying to extract all the data from Clockify into Excel using VBA and using below code but there is no output coming with that code
Your help will be much appreciated.

Getting this reponse when run the code `{"code":405,"message":"HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed"}`

```
Public Sub GetAllProjects()
    
Dim httpCaller As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Set httpCaller = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

httpCaller.Open "GET", "https://reports.api.clockify.me/v1/workspaces/*****/reports/detailed"
httpCaller.setRequestHeader "X-Api-Key", CLOCKIFY_API_KEY
httpCaller.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
httpCaller.send
Debug.Print httpCaller.responseText
    
End Sub
```

Comment: https://clockify.me/developers-api Unless you tell us which API method you're calling so we can see an example JSON response it's not clear how we can really help here.  None of the example responses seem to have a top-level key named "data" though

Comment: Sorry to bother you using this method `https://reports.api.clockify.me/v1/workspaces/*****/reports/detailed` along with `Api-Key` Yeah you are right this could be the issue because the names are not correct here. Let me correct them Thanks

Comment: "Detailed report" is a POST not a GET, and requires a JSON request body...   If you `Debug.Print http.responseText` what do you see?

Comment: Here it is `{"code":405,"message":"HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed"}`

Comment: There's your problem then - you need to review the API docs and form your request as outlined there.

Comment: I am using this same `API Key` and `https://reports.api.clockify.me/v1/workspaces/*****/reports/detailed` in Power Query where it is working fine why not in VBA

Comment: I'm not a Power Query user so I don't know what the difference would be, but if you're calling the API directly then you need to use a POST as documented on the API site.

Comment: Thank you yeah i know its my mistake i find the solution here when made a post request. But unable to modify the code according to the POST request. [POST Request](https://forum.clockify.me/t/please-provide-a-detailed-filter/875/4) if you can help with i would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A POST would look something like this in VBA:

```vb
Public Sub GetAllProjects()
    
    Dim httpCaller As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60, body As String, obj As Object, json As Object, result
    Dim ti As Object
    
    'not sure how much of the request body is required....
    'adjust dates below as needed
    body = "{""dateRangeStart"": ""2020-05-10T00:00:00.000"", " & vbLf & _
            " ""dateRangeEnd"": ""2020-05-16T23:59:59.000"", " & vbLf & _
            " ""detailedFilter"": {""page"": 1,""pageSize"": 50}} "
    Debug.Print body
    
    Set httpCaller = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    With httpCaller
        .Open "POST", "https://reports.api.clockify.me/v1/workspaces/*****/reports/detailed"
        .setRequestHeader "X-Api-Key", CLOCKIFY_API_KEY
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
        .send body  'include JSON body
        result = .responseText
        Debug.Print "---Response---" & vbLf & result
    End With
    
    Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(result)
    
    For Each obj In json("totals")
        Debug.Print "------"
        Debug.Print obj("totalTime")
        Debug.Print obj("totalBillableTime")
        Debug.Print obj("entriesCount")
        Debug.Print obj("totalAmount")
    Next obj
    
    For Each obj In json("timeentries")
        Debug.Print "------"
        Debug.Print obj("_id")
        Debug.Print obj("description")
        'etc etc
        'access the "timeinterval" sub-dictionary
        Set ti = obj("timeInterval")
            Debug.Print , ti("start")
            Debug.Print , ti("end")
            Debug.Print , ti("duration")
    Next obj

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much it is working very smoothly. Sorry to bother you again if you can parse it through JSON.

Comment: See update above - should get you started

Comment: Getting an error `Object Require`  `{"code":401,"message":"Unauthorized"}` on the line `For Each obj In json("totals") ' "totals" key holds a Collection`

Comment: Did `Debug.Print "---Response---" & vbLf & result` give you that `{"code":401,"message":"Unauthorized"}` ?  If Yes then something is not working with your access token/key

Comment: I did it now everything is working fine `"timeInterval":{"start":"2022-07-06T21:01:30+05:00","end":"2022-07-06T21:34:34+05:00","duration":1984}` but how to parse this time i am unbale to do that.

Comment: See edit above...